# Can Julia be used to create a large-scale CFD software like OpenFOAM?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, hpc, openfoam, julia

I have some experience with some programming languages like C/C++, Fortran, Python, etc but recently, I am getting interested in Julia.

But, I am wondering if Julia could be used to create some large CFD software like OpenFOAM (written in C++): mesh utilities, solvers, parallel computing, ...etc.

So my question, is Julia really up to this task for such scales?

Comment: Any programming language can be used for these things. What are your constraints/goals? Do you want to be fast? Write small code? Be interoperable with existing libraries?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Exactly, availability of libraries, how mature are they, High performance computing, speedup compared to C++, scalability, how easy is the maintainability of the code compared to C++

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician This is very subjective as long as your question does not contain more concrete criteria. Maybe you could add what you care about, e.g., performance of common math operations, integration with common numeric libraries, or whatever you are thinking of.

Comment: I think the question is just too subjective to answer. In the end, there are excellent C++ libraries for nearly everything that has to do with the solution of PDEs, whereas they are largely missing in the Julia environment. Examples that come to mind are PETSc/Trilinos for linear algebra, deal.II/libmesh/FEniCS for discretizations, etc. You will have to duplicate many many many years of work if you want to do all of that in Julia. Is it possible? Yes, of course. Is it worth it -- no, not at all.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: That's exactly the kind of answer I am exepecting, I mean, is it really worth it so as you said, that's a huge extra work. but what if Julia can Interface to C++ libraries?

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician You'd still have to write these interfaces. I mean, to give just a few examples, PETSc has ~500k lines of code, Trilinos has 1+M lines of code, deal.II has ~1.5M lines of code. Each of these has many thousands of public functions for which you would have to write interfaces. Is your love of Julia so great that you're willing to do that over just using these libraries' native language?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Could you please add that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the question is just too subjective to answer. In the end, there are excellent C++ libraries for nearly everything that has to do with the solution of PDEs, whereas they are largely missing in the Julia environment.

Examples that come to mind are PETSc/Trilinos for linear algebra, deal.II/libmesh/FEniCS for discretizations, etc. You will have to duplicate many many many years of work if you want to do all of that in Julia. Is it possible? Yes, of course. Is it worth it -- no, not at all.

To give you an idea of the level of work necessary: My best guess is that every finishing graduate student's software project based on deal.II runs through maybe 200,000 lines of C++ code in deal.II and, if it uses any kind of interesting linear solver, another 100,000 lines of code in solver packages. But experienced, full-time programmers only write 20,000 lines of code per year -- in other words, these students' programs would have taken 15 years to write if not for existing software libraries.

Comment: But Julia has some bindings for PETSc: https://github.com/JuliaParallel/PETSc.jl

Comment: @Navaro Alright, so you found that *one* of these libraries has *some* Julia bindings. But are they complete? Are they kept updated? What about all of the other libraries? I have no idea whether these binds are complete and up to date, but I think you get the point.

Comment: Just to quote from that page: "Just enough KSP functions are implimented to do a GMRES solve. Adding more functionality is the current priority." PETSc also has a million optional dependencies for preconditioners, solvers, and basically everything else. Are these all available? If not, you're basically back to what I described.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumptions that: 1) It takes the same amount of effort to write a program in C++ than in Julia. 2) All the work done so far in these libraries has to be duplicated in Julia. In reality, writing in Julia is much more productive and second, a lot of the work can be spread out in the community given Julia's excellent composability.

Comment: @balborian I would love to see actual evidence for your claim that "In reality, writing in Julia is much more productive". As for "spreading out work in the community" -- what do you think the packages developing in C++ do? Have you looked at the very long list of contributors to deal.II (https://dealii.org/authors.html) or PETSc (https://github.com/petsc/petsc/graphs/contributors) or Trilinos (https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/graphs/contributors) for example? Just to be clear, github cuts off the last two pages after 100 names, but there are many many more.

Comment: One example is https://github.com/gridap/Gridap.jl which has been developed by a small team in less than two years and is as practical and performant as FEniCS. You can find more details on my answer on https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/like-julia-scales-productive-insights-julia-developer/

Comment: @balborian That second link reads like a nice marketing piece. In the end, as I say in my answer above, I believe that it isn't actually about the programming language. I believe that at some fundamental level, the language doesn't matter. Maybe Julia is 20% faster to develop in than C++, or maybe it's the other way around. The difference is relatively minor. The difficulty in large scientific software is not in the language support, but in the algorithms, and in interacting with the whole ecosystem. I think I can say this from experience: I've been developing scientific software for 25 years.